# Linux Kernel Threads Issue

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

How to clear the memory used by the kernel threads.

I have used kthread_run() multiple times (example around 300000 times), and do_exit() from the thread function.

Memory increases for every kthread_run(), is it a correct way to call kthread_run() multiple times?

The requirement is that, I need to call the thread function, for every xxx time and do the cleanup.

Any inputs will be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Srinivasa Raghavan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by clearing the cache memory from the command prompt by the following command.

sync; echo 1 /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

Thanks !!!